# Is there anyway to use javascript get the attributes determined by CSS?

Tags: javascript

For example,

```
<html>
  <head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css"></head>
    <body>
      <img id="tmp"></img>
    </body>
</html>
```

in theme.css

```
img#tmp{
      width:120px;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      }
```

Is there anyway that I can get the width of the image "tmp" directly by JavaScript? Something like
`var temp=document.getElementById("tmp"); var width=temp.style.width`?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
getComputedStyle( elem ).getPropertyValue( 'width' )
```

where `elem` is the DOM element.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/7h4cg/

Btw, some older versions of some browsers do not support this code. If you need a cross-browser solution, use a cross-browser library.

Answer (score 0):

You'll definitely want JQuery's help on this. [Here](http://api.jquery.com/category/css/) is the list of all JQuery functions that can help you access all the style information you would want (hopefully).

Btw, if you're not familiar with some sort of Javascript library, it's probably a good idea to learn one.

Answer (score 0):

I 2nd Nadir's motion, however in your direct example you can change your code to:

```
var temp=document.getElementById("tmp");
var width=temp.style.width;
```

In your own example, you have used the getElementById incorrectly by pluralizing it.

[This comment](http://forums.devshed.com/javascript-development-115/javascript-getelementsbyid-99220.html) sums up why.

Comment: @Danjah This will only work if the `width` property was set inline (inside the `style` attribute), which is *not* the case with OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

What you're after is the computed style of the element. As usual, IE6-8 does it differently, so we need to do some sniffing:

```
var getStyle = window.getComputedStyle ? function (elem, prop) {
    var styles = getComputedStyle(elem, null);
    return prop ? styles[prop] : styles;
} : function (elem, prop) {
    return prop ? elem.currentStyle : elem.currentStyle[prop];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my cross-browser inline function:

```
function getComputedStyle(elem, styleAttr){
    return (elem.currentStyle ? elem.currentStyle : document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elem, null))[styleAttr];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers will return the literal style width and height, as it was written in the css- pehaps as a pecentage or an em multiple, while others translate all style dimensions to pixels.

In this case, I'd use `document.getElementById('tmp').offsetWidth` to be sure to get the rendered width in pixels, no matter how it was assigned.